# Update only checked rows php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, rows, multipleselection

I am trying to update only checked rows in the table but nothing is happening 
Here is my code

```
<?php
    //database connect select
    $result=mysql_query("Select * from ticket_reservation WHERE 
    validate_status='No'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' id='name'  name='name[]'value=".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['userid']."</td> <td>".$row['busid']."</td><td>".$row['numberofseats']."</td></tr>";
        echo "<br>"; 
    }
    echo"<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' Value='Validate Tickets'>    </td></tr>";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(is_array($_POST['name']))
        {
            $qry = "UPDATE ticket_reservation SET validate_status='Yes' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $_POST['name']).")";
            // echo $qry; // For checking the generated sql statement; can be removed
            mysql_query($qry);
        }
    }

?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: you're missing an underscore here `$POST`

Answer (score 2):

```
$checkbox=$_POST['name'];
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
{
    $id = $checkbox[$i];

    $sql1 = "UPDATE ticket_reservation set     validate_status='Yes' where id = '".$id."' ";
    mysql_query($sql1);
}
```

Comment: I have checked this answer but does not work

Answer (score 1):

You got also a typo here: `is_array($POST['name'])` should be `is_array($_POST['name'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MySQL` [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function to update all datasets in one query. So you don't need to iterate over all IDs using `foreach` loop.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(is_array($_POST['name']))
    {
        $qry = "UPDATE ticket_reservation SET validate_status='Yes' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $_POST['name']).")";
        echo $qry; // For checking the generated sql statement; can be removed
        mysql_query($qry);
    }
}
```

To prevent SQL Injection you should use prepared statements (see [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php))

You should also add a space between your HTML attributes: `name='name[]' value=` instead of `name='name[]'value=`.

Comment: I have added spaces and I have also added the above line but nothing is happening The validate status field does not change values in the database

Comment: Could you please add `echo $qry;` to your code and check the generated query in e.g. `phpMyAdmin`?

Comment: I am trying to iterate because I want to update multiple rows at a time does that make sense?

Comment: The code echo $qry doesn't generate any output...

Comment: @BilalZia My example will also update multiple rows. I've updated my answer so that you can see where you have to update the sql statement and where to add the `echo $qry;`.

Comment: Unfortunately this time also no output is generated neither the fields in the database being changed

Comment: Please set the attribute `name` of your submit button to `submit` so that `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` will take effect.

Comment: It generates the following output....UPDATE ticket_reservation SET validate_status='Yes' WHERE id IN (

Comment: Please check your `php_error_log` for notices, warnings and fatal errors.

Comment: I opened php error log from cpanel it says cannot find php error log

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
 $Name=$_POST['name'];
foreach($Name as $N)
{

$qry="Update ticket_reservation SET validate-status='Yes' Where id='$N'";       echo $qry; // For checking the generated sql statement; can be removed
 mysql_query($qry);



}

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error sir I have tried it too many times checking for the typos...